# How to remove extra columns from Telerik RadGrid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I have extra empty columns being added to my RadGrid, I don't know why they are appearing. I have looked around and read varying answers to this, some say that it has to do with the postback event, but I don't have it programmatically set.

My markup for the RadGrid is

```
<div class="rGrid">
<telerik:RadGrid ID="rgResults" runat="server" AlternatingItemStyle-BackColor="LightBlue"
    AllowSorting="True" OnNeedDataSource="rgResults_NeedDataSource" GridLines="Both" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="15" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
    <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="LightBlue"></AlternatingItemStyle>

    <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="True" AllowSorting="true">

    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

The OnNeedDataSource method is this..

```
protected void rgResults_NeedDataSource(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
    {
        string strFilePath = @"C:\PIA\CSV\FinalizedPIAData.csv";
        rgResults.DataSource = PIAScrape.ConvertCSVtoDataTable(strFilePath);
    }
```

I got no idea why it shows two extra columns that are empty, I have never seen happen before when using a RadGrid, but then again when I was using the RadGrid before, the datasource was always a SQL Function and bound it that way. This my first time binding to a CSV file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the **AutoGenerateColumns** property to **false** and define only the columns you need. Probably some empty fields come from your data source, so you should debug that as well and see what your ConvertCSVtoDataTable() method returns.

Comment: I figured it out the other night, I had to define the columns. The problem was within a loop for the Headers, my counting was off. So once I defined the columns everything worked.

Comment: Its Telerik radgrid bug.Even telerik dont have solution for this.And solution given by them are not working.This error mostly comes with Frozen property of radgrid